# ¿Como agregar un elemento a LabelWidget?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, interfaz-gráfica

Buenos dias amigos, estoy programando en [python](/questions/tagged/python), con la libreria grafica [tkinter](/questions/tagged/tkinter), mi pregunta es la siguiente:

## Pregunta

¿Como puedo realizar esto?

## Ejemplo

[image: LabelFrame widget]

Answer (score 0):

## Solución:

```
import tkinter as tk

def fun():
    label_frame.config({"labelwidget":titulo})
    
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("300x100")
label_frame = tk.LabelFrame(root)
label_frame.pack(pady=10)

titulo = tk.Label(label_frame, text="Titulo lol?")
titulo.pack(side="top")

str_var = tk.StringVar()
entrada = tk.Entry(label_frame, textvariable = str_var)
entrada.pack()

boton = tk.Button(label_frame, text="Push me!", command=fun)
boton.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Yo no sabia como hacer esto hasta hace unos minutos xD, es algo básico tal vez, pero puede haber alguien que quiera saber, como se puede hacer esto

## Resultado:

Antes

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Despues

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]